# Running JMS Bridge with HornetQ

Tags: jms, hornetq, bridge

I have two standalone HornetQ servers on same the machine! I followed jms-bridge example in HornetQ examples for configuring *source server* and *target server* (I copied configurations from example to my servers). When i want running target server (that contains jms bridge) It can not find TransactionManager property of JMSBridge bean, because *com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple* is not in server classpath. What should i choose instead of this implementation of TransactionManager? Or what jar files required for *com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple*?

```
   <!-- The JMS Bridge -->
   <bean name="JMSBridge" class="org.hornetq.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl">
           <constructor>
               <!-- Source ConnectionFactory Factory -->
               <parameter>
                   <inject bean="SourceCFF"/>
               </parameter>
               <!-- Target ConnectionFactory Factory -->
               <parameter>
                   <inject bean="TargetCFF"/>
               </parameter>
               <!-- Source DestinationFactory -->
               <parameter>
                   <inject bean="SourceDestinationFactory"/>
               </parameter>
               <!-- Target DestinationFactory -->
               <parameter>
                   <inject bean="TargetDestinationFactory"/>
               </parameter>
               <!-- Source username (no username here) -->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- Source password (no password here)-->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- Target username (no username here)-->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- Target password (no password here)-->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- Selector -->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- Interval to retry in case of failure (in ms) -->
               <parameter>5000</parameter>
               <!-- Maximum number of retries to connect to the source and target -->
               <parameter>10</parameter>
               <!-- Quality of service -->
               <parameter>ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE</parameter>
               <!-- Maximum batch size -->
               <parameter>1</parameter>
               <!-- Maximum batch time (-1 means infinite) -->
               <parameter>-1</parameter>
               <!-- Subscription name (no subscription name here)-->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- client ID  (no client ID here)-->
               <parameter><null /></parameter>
               <!-- concatenate JMS messageID to the target's message header -->
               <parameter>true</parameter>
               <!-- register the JMS Bridge in the JMX MBeanServer -->
               <parameter>
                   <inject bean="MBeanServer"/>
               </parameter>
               <parameter>org.hornetq:service=JMSBridge</parameter>
           </constructor>
           <property name="transactionManager">
               <inject bean="TransactionManager"/>
           </property>

           <!-- HornetQ JMS Server must be started before the bridge -->
           <depends>JMSServerManager</depends>

       </bean>
      <!-- TransactionManager -->
      <bean name="TransactionManager" class="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple">
       </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these jar files and error gone:

1. jta.jar
2. narayana-jta.jar

Answer (score 0):

you could chek out the new HornetQ book at

[HornetQ Messaging Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518408)